# What version is my MacBook hardware?

Tags: mac, macbook, specifications

I've seen links on the web about going into **Apple > About This Mac** but it doesn't tell me information specific enough to help me purchase new RAM. Namely, the specific version of my Mac.

Here is what System Information says

```
Model Name:            MacBook
Model Identifier:      MacBook2,1
Processor Name:        Intel Core 2 Duo
Processor Speed:       2 GHz
Number Of Processors:  1
Total Number Of Cores: 2
L2 Cache:              4 MB
Memory:                1 GB
Bus Speed:             667 MHz
Boot ROM Version:      MB21.00A5.B07
```

On [macsales](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/MacBook/DDR2/)  I see the following text

- MacBook 1.83GHz and 2.0GHz models with Core Duo support maximum of 2.0GB memory installed
- MacBook 1.83GHz and 2.0GHz Core 2 Duo Models (May/2007) support maximum of 4.0GB memory installed, MacBook 2.0GHz Core 2 Duo ‘Santa Rosa’ (Nov/2007) models Apple Factory specification maximum 4.0GB. OWC tested to support a maximum of 6.0GB.

I bought my MacBook in November 2007 but don't know which one I got. How can I or other Mac users find out which hardware version they have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Note, the first item in your quote from OWC is “Core Duo”, not “Core **2** Duo”.)

According to [apple-history.com](http://www.apple-history.com/), the ones with the 667Mhz bus are the May/2007 model.

OWC's MyOWC function says that the November/2007 MacBooks are “MacBook3,1”.

Some useful sites to identify Macs:

- [apple-history.com](http://www.apple-history.com/)
- [ifixit.com: ID Your Mac](http://www.ifixit.com/Info/ID-your-Mac)
- [OWC: MyOWC/Upgrade Center](http://eshop.macsales.com/MyOWC/index.cfm)
- [Apple: Support](http://www.apple.com/support/) (search for “how to indetify *yourModel*; e.g. [How to visually identify your black or white MacBook model](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1635)

  - The bottom of [Mac OS X versions (builds) included with Intel-based Macs](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1159) includes a list of “how to identify *yourModel*” for Intel models
- The application [Mactracker](http://mactracker.dreamhosters.com/) has a “This Mac” feature that seems like it might identify the Mac on which it is running.

Comment: Argh I did not mean to -1 this. The accept button on android browser does not work and I also have fat fingers!. Will fix this when I am home

Comment: You'll need to edit this answer for me to revert the -1. so sorry. I do care about your rep.

Comment: ok I fixed my -1 mistake. thanks for your answer!