# Can I install more than 4GB Ram on my mid-2008 macbook pro?

Tags: memory, macbook-pro, memory-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I determine which MacBook hardware version I have? (for RAM purchase)](https://superuser.com/questions/70480/how-do-i-determine-which-macbook-hardware-version-i-have-for-ram-purchase)

I have a mid-2008 Penryn 2.5 GHz with 800 MHz bus speed.

I have read that these machines can run with a 4gb and 2gb stick despite officially being limited to 4gb.

Is this true? How for sure is it to work, if so.

Comment: OS X is a hybrid OS, running a 32-bit kernel with 64-bit extensions (or pure 64-bit if you press the right key combo at startup). Whether or not the hardware supports it, the OS should. I'd plug it in and see for myself if it works.

Comment: Seriously? the linked duplicate does not address the question I have. I read that question before posting mine. It's about how to determine which version of mac you have and has no information about RAM other than being mentioned in the question. If my question is going to be closed, please supply an actual identical question for me to look at since I did search before posting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read up on this too. My understanding is yes it works, however you will sacrifice some speed to do it because the memory has to be accessed differently. Unless you really need the memory, I'd not bother and just save up for a new machine.