# How can I tell which MacBook Pro I have?

Tags: mac, macbook, macbook-pro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I determine which MacBook hardware version I have? (for RAM purchase)](https://superuser.com/questions/70480/how-do-i-determine-which-macbook-hardware-version-i-have-for-ram-purchase)

On my old IBM, I could just flip the laptop over and see what model & year my laptop was.

How can I get that info on my MBP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the on the Apple icon on the menu bar, hold down option, and "about this Mac" should turn into "system profiler…". You should see something for "model identifier" like `MacBookPro3,1`. Search Wikipedia for that model identifier.